# how to solve the warning Unrecognised tag: 'snapshotPolicy'?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When `maven build` there is a warning:

```
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'snapshotPolicy' (position: START_TAG seen ...</url>\n          <snapshotPolicy>... @269:27)  @ C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\settings.xml, line 269, column 27
```

The config file section is:

```
   <profile>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Nexus</name>
      <url>http://172.16.1.79:8082/repository/maven-public/</url>
      <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
```

Is there a problem?

the demo config is as follow:

```
<profile>
  <id>jdk-1.4</id>
  <activation>
    <jdk>1.4</jdk>
  </activation>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jdk14</id>
      <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
      <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
```

[image]

how to solve the warning Unrecognised tag: 'snapshotPolicy' , I can't found the maven office website [here](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#h5o-11)

Answer (score 2):

See how the offending tag goes within `releases` and `snapshots` tags. Placed there, it works.

```
<!--http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation-->
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>nexus</id>
                <name>Nexus</name>
                <url>http://172.16.1.79:8082/repository/maven-public/</url>
                
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Your answer looks OK, however it would be nice to explain how and _why_ you changed this settings snippet. Can't find where the snapshotPolicy came from in OP's settings, but you may explain how you replaced it with two updatePolicy tags, and link to the reference documentation that mentions this tag, e.g. https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories